# How to share the same ViewModel between Activity and Service when ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated?

Tags: android, mvvm, lifecycle

In new androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0 library, ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated. It suggested that we should

```
 * @deprecated Use the 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate or
 * {@link ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)},
 * passing in the activity.
```

However, I want to share the same ViewModel instance between an activity and a service, I cannot use 'by viewModels()' delegation. Could anyone point out what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just go with ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomViewModel::class.java) (in Kotlin)

Comment: @ Sanket Vekariya This can only used in Activity, how can I access ViewModel instance created via this method in my Service?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just replace it, with 
**In Activity:**
**Kotlin:** `ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomViewModel::class.java)`
**Java:** `ViewModelProvider(this).get(CustomViewModel.class)`
**In Service:**
create an instance of viewModel with keyword **new** inside service class
these work for me :)

Comment: This can only used in Activity, how can I access ViewModel instance created via this method in my Service?

Comment: @Robin Have you got your answer?

Comment: If I create a new instance, how could I share the same instance created in activity/fragment?

Comment: Sorry @SanketVekariya, this doesn't answer the question.  You can't use this inside a service.  So how can the service access a SharedViewModel?